# Cookie expiration is setting wrong

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I use PHP Header to set a persistent cookie in browsers. The PHP Header looks like this

```
$uuid = vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)), 4));
header( "Set-Cookie: userid=$uuid ; Expires=Wed, 28 Oct 2020 14:28:00 GMT;  Path=/ ; secure ; httpOnly ;SameSite=Strict" );
```

When I do this, even though the expiration period is set to `Wed, 28 Oct 2020 14:28:00 GMT`, the expiration date seems to be after about 6-8 hrs when I check with a cookie editor plugin on chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask why you're setting the cookie that way and not using [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) ?

Comment: I tried that too.. but the expiration didn't work well.

Comment: The setcookie function uses a UNIX timestamp to set the expiration time. 
Eg. `setcookie("userid", $uuid, time()+3600);`  -  Expires in one hour.

Comment: It also couldn't hurt to set your [default timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`